# OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException inside Lambda Expression C#

Tags: c#, selenium, lambda

I am debugging a project and have been getting NoSuchElementExceptions that say "Unable to find element with id == txtUserId" while I am debugging. The problem is the code is using lambda expressions to return an object so it is difficult to catch the NoSuchElementExceptions because it makes the object out of scope for the rest of the method.

```
try
{
   var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
   var itxtUserId = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("txtUserId")));

   //Clear the textbox 'UserID' then fill it with the user ID
   itxtUserId.Clear();
   itxtUserId.SendKeys("UserID");
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
   // I have code here to handle exceptions
}
```

I have read http://watirmelon.com/2014/01/23/checking-an-element-is-present-in-c-webdriver/ which suggests writing global variables that are helper methods to prevent these types of errors from occuring in the first place. However, I have heard that many developers frown upon the use of global variables and that they can cause problems. Also I feel it is still necessary to be able to handle the exceptions so the program can get back on track during runtime. Therefore how do you handle exceptions within Lambda expressions? Is there a way to return this object without the Lambda expression? Statements like these are throughout the code base and they look like the [examples](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) from the Selenium documentation but they constantly throw exceptions.

Here is a stack trace from "Unable to find element with id == txtSearchByLastName"

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var textUserSearch = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id(strElementId)));

at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecuteDictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Id>b__0(ISearchContext context)
at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
at Automation_Solution.Navigate.<>c__DisplayClassc.<PatientSearch>b__b(IWebDriver d) in c:\Users\username\Source\Workspaces\TestSuite\Solution\Solution\Navigation.cs:line 226
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
```

Comment: I'm not sure your assumption about lambda expressions spawning new threads is accurate. I don't believe that's a feature of lambda expressions in and of themselves in .NET. Can you supply a citation for that belief? As for breaking on the exception, make sure your debugger settings are only breaking on I caught exceptions (Debug > Exceptions...)

Comment: I wasn't being clear about the Lambda expressions, basically what is happening is the Exception is being thrown when the Lambda is called but I don't want that the thrown exception to stop the application from running, I would rather catch them and have code for the program to get back on track.

Comment: Again, double-check your settings in the Exceptions dialog under the Debug menu in Visual Studio. The box under "thrown" should be unchecked.

Comment: I unchecked "OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException" and now the system is not interrupted by the error, thank you.

Comment: I'll promote this to an answer, which you can then accept as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've got "Break on all thrown exceptions" set in your project. In Visual Studio, select `Exceptions...` from the Debug menu. In the Exceptions dialog, make sure that the check box for under "Thrown" is unchecked.

[image: Exceptions Dialog Screenshot]

Comment: This is happening to me even though my "Thrown" checkboxes are all unchecked.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you need:

```
var itxtUserId = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("txtUserId"))).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because it shows a fundamental lack of understanding about the WebDriver API, and the `WebDriverWait` class in particular. It supplies a link to Java documentation, when the poster is using C# code. Most concerningly, it doesn't recognize that the `WebDriverWait` class ignores `NoSuchElementException` by default, so there's no need to explicitly include it.